# conditional cast of sObject to Custom Object in Apex salesforce

Tags: apex, cpu

I have a case where I hit CPU limit (records creation operation that takes longer than Salesforce allows).
I see as one example they advise using maps instead of Lists

but I cannot get how I can use MAP to insert a bunch of new records when the template used for object creation is not exactly the same as the original object.

See example below

```
public with sharing class BatchCreateNonSerializedParts implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    String ProjectConfigID;
    String ProjectID;
    Integer VehicleFleetStartNumber;
    ComponentProjectConfiguration__c ProjectConfig;

    List<NonSerializedPart__c> NonSerPartsConfig;
    List<project_Non_Serialized_Part__c> NonSerParts = new List<project_Non_Serialized_Part__c>();
    List<Acceptance__c> NonSerPartAcceptances = new List<Acceptance__c>();  


    public BatchCreateNonSerializedParts(String ProjectConfigID, String ProjectID) {
        this.ProjectConfigID = ProjectConfigID;
        this.ProjectID = ProjectID;

        ProjectConfig = [Select ID, Name, Vehicle_fleet_start_number__c from ComponentProjectConfiguration__c where ID =: ProjectConfigID];
        VehicleFleetStartNumber = Integer.valueOf(ProjectConfig.Vehicle_fleet_start_number__c);

        NonSerPartsConfig = [Select ID, Name, Number_of_units__c, Quantity__c, Unit_of_measurement__c, Material_Number__c, Supplier_Part_Number__c, Supplier__c from NonSerializedPart__c where Project__c =: ProjectConfigID];
        
        // use map instead 
        // Map<id, NonSerializedPart__c>  NSPM = new Map<id, NonSerializedPart__c>([Select ID, Name, Number_of_units__c, Quantity__c, Unit_of_measurement__c, Material_Number__c, Supplier_Part_Number__c, Supplier__c from NonSerializedPart__c where Project__c =: ProjectConfigID]);
        // NonSerParts = NSPM.values();

        for (NonSerializedPart__c part : NonSerPartsConfig) {
        Double Total = part.Number_of_units__c * part.Quantity__c;
        project_Non_Serialized_Part__c NewPart = New project_Non_Serialized_Part__c(Name = part.Name, Project__c =ProjectID,
        Material_Number__c = part.Material_Number__c, Supplier__c = part.Supplier__c, 
        Supplier_Part_Number__c = part.Supplier_Part_Number__c, 
        Total_Quantity__c = Total ,Unit_of_measurement__c = part.Unit_of_measurement__c,
        Number_of_units__c = part.Number_of_units__c, unit_Quantity__c = part.Quantity__c);

        NonSerParts.add(NewPart);
        
        }
        insert NonSerParts;
        for(project_Non_Serialized_Part__c part : NonSerParts){ 
                
            for(Integer i=0;i<part.Number_of_units__c;i++){
                    Acceptance__c newAcceptance = new Acceptance__c(Non_Serialized_Part__c = part.id, Quantity__c = part.unit_Quantity__c,
                    Unit_of_measurement__c = part.Unit_of_measurement__c, Acceptance_Non_Serialized_Part__c = part.Name, Status__c = 'NOT SENT');  
                    NonSerPartAcceptances.add(newAcceptance);
                }
               // System.debug('Acceptances size: ' + NonSerPartAcceptances.size());
        }

    }
    
    public Iterable<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

       return NonSerPartAcceptances;
    }
    
    public static void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Acceptance__c> NonSerPartAcceptances) {

        for(Acceptance__c a : NonSerPartAcceptances){ 
            insert a;
        }   
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // AsyncApexJob a = [Select a.TotalJobItems, a.Status, a.NumberOfErrors,
        // a.JobType, a.JobItemsProcessed, a.ExtendedStatus, a.CreatedById,
        // a.CompletedDate From AsyncApexJob a WHERE id = :BC.getJobId()];
        // // get the job Id
        // System.debug('$$$ Jobid is'+BC.getJobId());
        
        System.debug('Succesfully inserted Non Serialized parts and Acceptances');
    }
}
```

and my trails in debug

```
// List<project_Non_Serialized_Part__c> NonSerParts = new List<project_Non_Serialized_Part__c>();
List<NonSerializedPart__c> NonSerPartsConfig = new List<NonSerializedPart__c>();
List<SObject> NonSer; // = List<SObject>();
Map<id, NonSerializedPart__c>  NSPM = new Map <id, NonSerializedPart__c>([Select ID, Name, Number_of_units__c, Quantity__c, Unit_of_measurement__c, Material_Number__c, Supplier_Part_Number__c, Supplier__c from NonSerializedPart__c where Project__c =: 'a3ae0000003ZTBmAAO']);

List<project_Non_Serialized_Part__c> NonSerParts;
// ids are ids of the object quered. ok
Set<id> ids = NSPM.keySet();
NonSer =  NSPM.values();

//NonSerParts = (project_Non_Serialized_Part__c) NonSer;

/* project_Non_Serialized_Part__c NewPart = New project_Non_Serialized_Part__c(Name = part.Name, Project__c =ProjectID,
        Material_Number__c = part.Material_Number__c, Supplier__c = part.Supplier__c, 
        Supplier_Part_Number__c = part.Supplier_Part_Number__c, 
        Total_Quantity__c = Total ,Unit_of_measurement__c = part.Unit_of_measurement__c,
        Number_of_units__c = part.Number_of_units__c, unit_Quantity__c = part.Quantity__c) 
*/

System.debug(ids);
System.debug(NonSer[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, a Map won't help here. You need to change your code so that you generate the records you need inside the execute method. This mostly involves reorganizing the code so that the NonSerializedPart__c records are processed in the execute method.

```
public with sharing class BatchCreateNonSerializedParts implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    String ProjectConfigID;
    String ProjectID;
    Integer VehicleFleetStartNumber;

    public BatchCreateNonSerializedParts(String ProjectConfigID, String ProjectID) {
        this.ProjectConfigID = ProjectConfigID;
        this.ProjectID = ProjectID;

        ComponentProjectConfiguration__c ProjectConfig = [
            Select ID, Name, Vehicle_fleet_start_number__c 
            from ComponentProjectConfiguration__c 
            where ID =: ProjectConfigID
        ];
        VehicleFleetStartNumber = Integer.valueOf(ProjectConfig.Vehicle_fleet_start_number__c);
    }
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            Select ID, Name, Number_of_units__c, Quantity__c, Unit_of_measurement__c, Material_Number__c, 
                Supplier_Part_Number__c, Supplier__c 
            from NonSerializedPart__c 
            where Project__c =: ProjectConfigID
            ]);
    }
    
    public static void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<NonSerializedPart__c> NonSerPartsConfig) {;
        List<Acceptance__c> NonSerPartAcceptances = new List<Acceptance__c>();
        List<project_Non_Serialized_Part__c> NonSerParts = new List<project_Non_Serialized_Part__c>();
        for (NonSerializedPart__c part : NonSerPartsConfig) {
            Double Total = part.Number_of_units__c * part.Quantity__c;
            project_Non_Serialized_Part__c NewPart = New project_Non_Serialized_Part__c(Name = part.Name, Project__c =ProjectID,
            Material_Number__c = part.Material_Number__c, Supplier__c = part.Supplier__c, 
            Supplier_Part_Number__c = part.Supplier_Part_Number__c, 
            Total_Quantity__c = Total ,Unit_of_measurement__c = part.Unit_of_measurement__c,
            Number_of_units__c = part.Number_of_units__c, unit_Quantity__c = part.Quantity__c);
            NonSerParts.add(NewPart);
        }
        insert NonSerParts;
        for(project_Non_Serialized_Part__c part : NonSerParts){ 
            for(Integer i=0;i<part.Number_of_units__c;i++){
                    Acceptance__c newAcceptance = new Acceptance__c(Non_Serialized_Part__c = part.id, Quantity__c = part.unit_Quantity__c,
                    Unit_of_measurement__c = part.Unit_of_measurement__c, Acceptance_Non_Serialized_Part__c = part.Name, Status__c = 'NOT SENT');  
                    NonSerPartAcceptances.add(newAcceptance);
                }
        }
        insert NonSerPartAcceptances;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug('Succesfully inserted Non Serialized parts and Acceptances');
    }
}
```

Also, a side note, do not insert records in a loop:

```
for(Acceptance__c a : NonSerPartAcceptances){ 
    insert a;
}
```